# Changing font size and side panel in Slidify with Shiny

Tags: slidify

I'm creating a slidify presentation that has shiny apps inside.

For example:

```
## Interactive Chart with Shiny Controls

{r opts.label = 'shiny'}
slidifyUI(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('sex', 'Choose Sex', c('Male', 'Female')),
    selectInput('type', 'Choose Type',
      c('multiBarChart', 'multiBarHorizontalChart')
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$div(id = 'googletables', class='shiny-html-output')
  )
)
```

and the app is

```
require(rCharts)
output$googletables <- renderGvis({gvisTable(Population, options=list(width="100%", height="100%"))})
```

I want to do two things:

1. Make the text on the table smaller
2. Change the design from a side panel to a floating panel, like in this [example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure about changing the size of the text in the tables but I was able to hack my way into a draggable panel in Ramnath's interactive example which appears to be the source of this code.  See my fork at http://github.com/timelyportfolio/interactive .  This requires the newest `shiny` and the dev branches of `slidify` and `slidifyLibraries`.  On the last slide I copied the code for `absolutePanel` from the superzip example.  I manually deleted replicated jquery assets and added some js/CSS from shiny in that subdirectory.  I will echo Ramnath's warning that this is highly experimental.